# Tracking WorkItem's Links changes in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

We have an App for TFS (Team Fondation Server). This application is partly offline it's syncronizing WorkItems to local base. To syncronize WorkItem changes we using "ChangedDate" field. It means that we syncronizing only Items which "ChangedDate" field older that last syncronization date.

But there one issue, if you are adding/removing/changing links in WorkItems, then the WorkItem itself isn't changing and its "ChangedDate" field isn't changed to, so we loose link changes during Syncronization.

Could you please help me, is there any way to track links changes in TFS, maybe there is something like wiql for links? Or maybe there is any way to query WorkItems which links were changed.

Best Regards,
Leonid.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)? It is much better to use that as a starting point to build syncing software with TFS than writing your own.

Comment: Unfortunately TFS Integration Platform will no longer be supported.